# Exchangeability of y1 and y2.

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian

I'm working through one of [Gelman's](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/book/BDA3.pdf)  exercises on exchangeability and am stuck on a seemingly simple exercise.  We are given a box with N black and white balls but we not know how many of each.  Task 1: We pick a ball and observe its color (y1), put it back, and then draw a second and observe its color (y2).  We want to know if y1 and y2 are exchangeable.  Task 2: we do the same as task 2 but without replacement.  I know that observations are exchangeable if the probabilities of the permutations of the observation are all equal.  Here is what I have for task 1 and 2 so far.  I am going to let $w$ be the number of white balls in the box so the number of black balls will be $N-w$.

Task 1 (with replacement)
\begin{align*}
    P(y_1 = black, y_2 = white) &= \frac{N-w}{N} \times\frac{w}{N} = \frac{Nw-w^2}{N^2}\\
    P(y_1 = black, y_2 = black) &= \frac{N-w}{N} \times\frac{N-w}{N} = \frac{(N-w)^2}{N^2}\\
    P(y_1 = white, y_2 = white) &= \frac{w}{N} \times\frac{w}{N} = \frac{w^2}{N^2}\\
    P(y_1 = white, y_2 = black) &= \frac{w}{N} \times\frac{N-w}{N} = \frac{Nw-w^2}{N^2}\\
\end{align*}

Task 2 (without replacement)
\begin{align*}
    P(y_1 = black, y_2 = white) &= \frac{N-w}{N} \times\frac{w}{N-1} = \frac{Nw-w^2}{N^2-N}\\
    P(y_1 = black, y_2 = black) &= \frac{N-w}{N} \times\frac{N-w-1}{N} = \frac{(N-w)(N-w-1)}{N^2-N}\\
    P(y_1 = white, y_2 = white) &= \frac{w}{N} \times\frac{w-1}{N-1} = \frac{w^2-w}{N^2-N}\\
    P(y_1 = white, y_2 = black) &= \frac{w}{N} \times\frac{N-w}{N} = \frac{Nw-w^2}{N^2-N}\\
\end{align*}

After playing around with some values for N and w, and some intuition, the probabilities for Task 1 (w/ replacement) are all the same when w is exactly half of N (i.e. the number of black balls is equal the white balls), and the probabilities for Task 2 (w/o replacement) are not all the same even with half of ball white and the other half black.

I feel like there is something I am missing having to do with the prior placed on the numbers of each color of ball.  According to Gelman et al, "with no information available to distinguish them, we have no logical choice but to model the θj’s exchangeably" [page 107].  Does this mean for Task 1 and 2 we can just state this assumption and assume the number of white and black balls are equal since we have no other "logical choice"?

Comment: Exchangeability, in this case, does not imply equal number of black and white balls.  Let $~f(x)~$ denote the probability that there are exactly $~x~$ white balls.  Let $~g(x)~$ denote the probability that there are exactly $~x~$ black balls.  Exchangeablility implies that for all $~x, ~f(x) = g(x).$

Comment: Would that not mean then that f(x) = g(x) = 0.5?  I'm working under the idea that exchangeability has to do with the order in which the events occur and that the probabilities of the different orders (i.e. permutations) are all the same.  Since this is under the umbrella of bayes statistics I am thinking there is a prior probability that I am not considering, as well not knowing how to apply it.

Comment: First of all, you have misinterpreted $~f(x)~$ and $~g(x)~.$  For example, if $~x = 0.1,~$ then my assertion is that the probability that $~0.1~$ of the balls are white is equal to the probability that $~0.1~$ of the balls are black.  Second of all, regardless of whether the colors $~y_1~$ and $~y_2~$ are the same, or different, I question whether Bayes Theorem will lead to the conclusion that $~f(0.5) = 1 = g(0.5).~$  That is, I don't see how you will be able to conclude that it is certain that (1/2) of the balls are white.

Comment: $y_1$ and $y_2$ are exchangeable if $\mathbb P(y_1=c , y_2=k) = \mathbb P(y_1=k , y_2=c)$ for each pair of colours $c,k \in \{black, white\}$. Here $c,k$ may be the same or different.  You do not need the numbers of black and white balls to be equal to show this. In the *without replacement* case you get equality with probabilities $\frac{b(b-1)}{n(n-1)}$ when both are black, $\frac{w(w-1)}{n(n-1)}$ when both are white, and $\frac{bw}{n(n-1)}$ when they are different colours, equivalent to what you have shown

Comment: I think I'm getting it... So in the w/o replacement case, both black and both white are equal because we don't know anything about the numbers so the probability forms are equal.  But for different colors probabilities are not equal to BB or WW because the probability takes a different form.  Is that the right thinking?  And thank you for helping!